# Using Content Organiser to Route to Subsites

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-organizer, content-organizer-rule, send-to-destination

I'm trying to set up Content Organiser to route documents from the root site of a site collection to libraries within it's subsites, but every time I try to set up a rule with the path to the subsite library I get the 'must provide a valid target' error (same error when the path is to either the Documents library or the Drop Off Library).

The structure is the root site > Project Site > Job Site. The root site needs to have CO rules to push to the Documents library in either of those subsites, based on the Content Type (Project Document or Job Document).

I've ticked the 'allow targets in another site' box in Content Organiser settings on all three sites, and both the subsites have been added as Send To locations in SP Admin > Records Management.

Can anyone help? This seems like a pretty serious deficiency in the Content Organiser and makes it pretty much useless unless you're happy storing everything in a single site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there's a delay in SPO (as there is with so many features, grr) between enabling 'allow other sites as a target' and the radio button actually showing up when you create a rule. Seems to be working as normal now, though the concept of chaining COs rather than sending directly to a document library seems counter-intuitive and adds extra workload.